# request.method == 'POST' is not working in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I created a form in template to insert data in database but form is not working.When i submitted form nothing happened.please review my all code and give me some suggestion.

**add.html Template file:**

```
        <h2>Add Article</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <label>Title</label>
              <input type="text" name="title" 
              placeholder="Enter Title">
             <label>Category</label>
                <select name="cate">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        {% for cat in get %}
                            <option value="{{ cat.cate }}">{{ cat.cate }}
                          </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </option>
                </select>
            <label>Discription</label>
                <textarea name="desc" rows="15">
               </textarea> 
              <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
         </form>
```

I created 2 views.in first view i rendered all categories which add in form select menu and 2nd view is for handling form

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import article, category

def get_category(request):
get = category.objects.all()
context = {
    'get':get
}
return render(request, 'blog/add.html', context)

def add(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    title = request.POST['title']
    cate = request.POST['cat']
    desc = request.POST['desc']
    art = article(title=title, disc=desc, cat=cate)
    art.save()

    return redirect('blog/index.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'blog/add.html')
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class category(models.Model):
   cate = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.cate

class article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   disc = models.TextField()
   cat = models.ForeignKey(category, verbose_name="Category")
   posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^add/$', views.get_category, name='category'),
   url(r'^add/$', views.add, name='add'),
 ]
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation problems in your code.

Comment: @habib your question is answered, as an addition, make use of `django forms`. Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/

Answer (score 1):

In your case every time action go to the get_category, because django find first match urls and use it for action.

You can create one function for your case:
in views.py

```
def category(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        # update start
        cat = request.POST['cat']
        cate = Category.objects.get(pk=cat)
        # Update end
        desc = request.POST['desc']
        art = article(title=title, disc=desc, cat=cate)
        art.save()
        return redirect('blog/index.html')

    get = category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'get':get
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/add.html', context)
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^add/$', views.get_category, name='category'),
   # !! comment or remove last urls
   # url(r'^add/$', views.add, name='add'),
 ]
```

I edit but if you look and rebuild your logic with [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) it will be better.

Comment: I changed my code according your suggestion and get this error:
**MultiValueDictKeyError at /add/**
"'cat'"

Comment: I changed some values now get this error:
**ValueError at /add/
Cannot assign "''": "article.cat" must be a "category" instance.**

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add item">`
Add a Submit button instead of type = 'button'

Answer (score 0):

reconfig project(makemigration and migrate) if POST method is not working

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
return redirect(request, 'blog/index.html')
```

To:

```
return redirect('index')
```

'index' is the name attribute of view function in views.py file. As redirect doesn't take 'request' argument as parametre.